# OpenOffice autocorrect glitch

Tags: openoffice

When entering the string "Jan" in Openoffice.org Calc, it is immediately replaced by "jan". This also happens if I

- Set the format of the cell to "text"
- Add an autocorrect-rule saying "jan" should be replaced with "Jan"

Any ideas as to what causes this? I figured it might have something to do with "jan" being short for january, but nothing happens when I enter "Feb".

Version number of OpenOffice: 3.3.0 (build 9567), Dutch version

Comment: Adding a space (or .) after Jan seems to work!

Comment: @BrianA: I've also found this workaround, but I'm still curious as to what might cause this weird behaviour.